# Dividing a page into 4 columns: how to keep ul lists grouped?

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I have the following page:

```
<div class="columns">
  <ul>
    <li class="first">B</li>
    <li>Beta</li>
    <li>Bravo</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="first">C</li>
    <li>Camera</li>
    <li>Chameleon</li>
    <li>Charlie</li>
    <li>Cream</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

with way more uls.

When I use

```
.columns {
  column-count: 4;
}
```

elements, per `li`, might end up on different columns. Is it possible to keep `ul`s grouped, so they only move in whole blocks?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `break-inside: avoid` on the child element.

[**CSS-Tricks break-inside**](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/break-inside/)

> Use avoid on an element within a multi-column layout to keep the
>   property from breaking apart.

```css
.columns {
  column-count: 4;
  -moz-column-count: 4;
  -webkit-column-count: 4;
}
ul {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
  <ul>
    <li class="first">B</li>
    <li>Beta</li>
    <li>Bravo</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="first">Camera</li>
    <li>Chameleon</li>
    <li>Charlie</li>
    <li>Cream</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="first">B</li>
    <li>Beta</li>
    <li>Bravo</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="first">Camera</li>
    <li>Chameleon</li>
    <li>Charlie</li>
    <li>Cream</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="first">B</li>
    <li>Beta</li>
    <li>Bravo</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="first">Camera</li>
    <li>Chameleon</li>
    <li>Charlie</li>
    <li>Cream</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="first">B</li>
    <li>Beta</li>
    <li>Bravo</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li class="first">Camera</li>
    <li>Chameleon</li>
    <li>Charlie</li>
    <li>Cream</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Now the `ul`s are horizontally spread out, instead of vertically. A-B-C-D  linebreak E-F-G-H instead of A-E-I linebreak B-F-J etc

Comment: I have updated my answer, I took the use-case of 4 columns only. Just figured out for 8 columns.

Comment: Managed to find the exact same properties as you did - haven't tested it cross browser yet, but even if they weren't to work, it'll be fine. I'll accept the answer ASAP!